# drf how to avoid objects.all() in UniqueValidator

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class that represents a user.

```
class UserSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    uid = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "all"

    def validate(self, data):
        super().validate(data)
        validate_user_data(data=self.initial_data, user=self.instance)
        return data
```

users should be unique on uid, so when getting a post request what I really want is to change the uid field to:

```
    uid = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, validators=[validators.UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
```

and this will probably work, the problem is, this will trigger an sql query that will select all the users.
This could have a very high impact on the system since there could be tens of thousands of them.
What I would really want is to change the query to `User.objects.get(uid=uid)`, which will not select every user from the DB.
However, since I'm in the serializer definition of uid, I can't use uid=uid because uid is just being defined.

Comment: Note that this will *not* trigger a `.all()` at the database. Django will fiter the queryset. The `queryset` you here provide acts as a "root queryset" from which other queries can arise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (…) and this will probably work, the problem is, this will trigger an sql query the will select all the users.

This is **incorrect**. Django will filter the queryset, but the filtering itself happens at the database side.

This will *not* query for all the items in the `User` table. The queryset is *not* evaluated. It acts as a "root queryset" against which queries will be constructed.

We can look up the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.x/rest_framework/validators.py#L36):

> ```
> class UniqueValidator(object):
>
>     # ...
>
>     def __call__(self, value):
>         queryset = self.queryset
>         queryset = self.filter_queryset(value, queryset)
>         queryset = self.exclude_current_instance(queryset)
>         if qs_exists(queryset):
>             raise ValidationError(self.message, code='unique')
> ```

Here the queryset is thus filtered. This filtering is not done at the Python/Django level, but it constructs a filtered variant. Indeed, if we look at the `filter_queryset` function, we see:

> ```
>     def filter_queryset(self, value, queryset):
>         """
>         Filter the queryset to all instances matching the given attribute.
>         """
>         filter_kwargs = {'%s__%s' % (self.field_name, self.lookup): value}
>         return qs_filter(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
> ```

with as `qs_filter`:

> ```
> def qs_filter(queryset, **kwargs):
>     try:
>         return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
>     except (TypeError, ValueError, DataError):
>         return queryset.none()
> ```

As you can see, it will thus generate a query `User.objects.filter(uid=the_uid).exclude(pk=item_that_is_updated)`

It will thus check if there is a `User` object in that database with the same `uid` as the one you set, and exclude the one your are updating (given that is applicable). The query this will look like:

```
SELECT user.*
FROM user
WHERE uid = the_uid
  AND id <> item_that_is_updated
```

It will thus filter at the database level, and therefore boost efficiency.